# Can MySQL Handle Geo Location

Tags: mysql

Say I want 20 closest businesses to a location.

Innodb doesn't support that. So what does?

Is it possible to have some tables in some engine and other tables on different engines?

Comment: Not sure if this is geo-ip related or a general mapping question.  If the former this might be relevant http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/06/01/implementing-efficient-geo-ip-location-system-in-mysql/

Comment: And yes, you can have varying storage engines per table in a given mysql database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use MyISAM for storing the geo location as they support the spatial data types.For more information please look [Saptial Datatypes in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html)

And You can also use the mix of engines there is no issues on that..

Comment: No issues? What about Foreign Keys?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to design an optimal schema, plus code, to find the 20 closest whatevers:

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng

Comment: How does this compare to spatial indexes? Pros and cons?

Comment: I have not benchmarked.  Mine is Order(1), so you can't get faster.

Comment: I somehow find this claim hard to believe, without benchmarks.